# a service which would be able to run jobs on a timed basis

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-services, asp.net-web-api2

I am working for my client using Asp.net webAPI2 and angularJS. Now my client have following requirement,but i am unable to understand what type of project i have to create like WebAPI project,window service or any other? Anyone please tell me what the client actually want and how can i do it?

QueueManager will need to be some kind of a service which would be able to run jobs on a timed basis.  We envision it being a service that runs on a continuous loop, but has a Thread.Sleep at the end of each iteration with a duration of x-seconds (“x” being set in a config file.)  You should create this QueueManager service as a new project within the Core.Jobs project; I would like to have the project name be “Core.Jobs.QueueManager”, along with the base namespace.
Here are the functions that the QueueManager will do for each iteration:

1)  Do a worker healthcheck (JobsAPI: Queue/WorkerHealthCheck – already created)
a.  This method will just return a 200 status code, and a count of workers.  Not need to act on the return value.

Comment: *Anyone please tell me what the client actually want* I believe that nobody, apart from your client, can tell you what HE wants. Anyway i suggest you to start looking and reading more about [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Look at Hangfire, it is quite easy to set up and simple to use.

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html